# Creating points projected on line using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, points-to-line, draw-interaction

How can we create points perpendicularly on a line with QGis ?

Otherwise, how can we draw a line between one point and a line ?

Here is a picture to show what we want :

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you only need to show these lines/points, you can do this with a **geometry generator** marker style. This is a fairly new feature in QGIS, and it makes it easy to do things that would have needed a database before. I did this in QGIS 2.18

I assume you have a line layer called "ligne", with a unique id field. I called this "unid", and set to 1

then use the following formula on your points layer in the geometry generator. **Make sure you set the output type to be "linestring"**. If it's not, nothing will appear.

```
shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('ligne','unid',1)))
```

Here's an example. I've using a normal dot symbol and a generator on the points layer

[image]

To show the points projected onto the line, add another geometry generator marker, this time make it a POINT

```
closest_point( geometry(get_feature('ligne','unid',1)), $geometry)
```

[image]

This is not guaranteed to be perpendicular to the line, for example:-

- if the point is near a vertex.
- if the point is far from the line

If a point is quite close to the line, the shortest line is likely to be perpendicular.