# Find the path inside a polygon by building graph

Tags: pyqgis, graph, dijkstra

I need to find the path inside a polygon. It should be the equidistant path from the polygon boundaries. Unfortunately I can't rasterize the polygon.
I thought it would be possible to construct a visibility graph from various points within the polygon. Then calculate the weight of its edges based on distance from the polygon boundary and apply Dijkstra algorythm to find the path.
But I have no idea how to calculate a weight for graph edges. For the shortest path is a distance between the xy coordinates of start and end nodes. But what is it for the equidistant path from the polygon boundaries? I could calculate distance from the graph nodes to the closest point of a polygon boundary by geometry expression but seems the difference of this distances for two points is not the weight of a graph edge.
May be somebody can help me?

The target part looks like this:
[image]

A created a lot of points inside a polygon and then I connected then with edges (green edges):
[image]

I used such geometry expression to calculate the distance of a point from the boundaries of the polygon:

```
cost = 1/distance($geometry,closest_point (overlay_within('polygon', boundary($geometry))[0], $geometry))
```

Then I tried to calculate weight of edge like this

```
weight = abs(G.nodes[node1]['cost'] - G.nodes[node2]['cost'])
```

and used Dijkstra’s algorithm but it works bad (red line):
[image]

Comment: Densify polygon boundaries. Compute voronoi polygons of vertices. Clip by parent polygon. Convert to lines. Delete lines that share line segment with polygon outline. Compute path between 2 points

Comment: **Why** can't you rasterize the polygon? Did you have a look here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/474196/88814

Comment: Yes, it'is great way, but I need to understand how the least path plugin works and I don't. I understood that it is Dijkstra's algorithm with Manhattan distance (like A* algorithm). And it means that this plugin uses a graph. But how it calculates weights of edges with color and distance I really don't understand even with the plugin. And I tried to figure out it by building my own graph but I failed

Comment: And I wrote that I cannot rasterize it because now I need to figure out how it works

Comment: You can try with a *medial axis* - a concept of point set theory basically covering your scenario. Might not be exactly what you want, though.

Comment: See help how to rasterize, it's quite easy: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize And the answer linked above explains in detail how to proceed.

Comment: Just saying, if *equidistancy* is the key weight here, a respective most cost efficient path between any two non-'adjacent' points inside the polygon must be along the medial axis.

Comment: @FelixIP Do you have any idea how to add start and end points into a Voronoi graph (if they don't lay on a middle line of Voronoi Diagram)? I almost draw a graph using Voronoi diagram but I don't know how to add them into a graph

Comment: Project points onto nearest edge and split edges at this points. This will add 6 edges to graph and 4 nodes.

Comment: @FelizIP Could you explain more how to project points? I'm new in QGIS and I know tools not so well.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/246551/156742