# Projects points to lines inside a polygon

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, graph, voronoi-thiessen, dijkstra

I try to project points onto a line layer. The line layer consists of lots of simple lines (I got it from Voronoj diagram, it is a center line of my polygon). I need to draw path from start point to end point following the polygon centerline and does not go beyond the polygon boundaries (it's important because the polygon can be very winding). When I created Voronoj diagram I cannot include start and end point here because the diagram goes around the points.

I tried very simple way to start with. I used geometry expression to project my point on middle line like the shortest path to line.

```
shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('line','unid',1)))
```

But it doesn't work. How can I create geometry expression for it?

[image]

###### Example data

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14jjiVjH3Z6VPX87QkjsQz2RcA26nxJGB?usp=sharing

Comment: Example is here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14jjiVjH3Z6VPX87QkjsQz2RcA26nxJGB?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line layer has a different CRS to your point layer, which is likely the reason the `shortest_line` function is not working.

You can collect together your line segments and perform a transformation within the `shortest_line` function like so:

```sql
shortest_line(
    @geometry, 
    transform(
        aggregate('line', 'collect', @geometry),
        'EPSG:3857',
        'EPSG:4326'
    )
)
```

The `@geometry` notation was introduced in QGIS 3.28. For earlier versions, use `$geometry`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, my expression differs from my layers because I got it from this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246541/creating-points-projected-on-line-using-qgis and it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to collect lines into 1 MultiString inside geometry expression? I have to merge them manually. I found that "collect" command can be good but I have no idea how to combine command "geometry(get_feature)" and "collect" because the current layer is a point layer and I need to collect different layer in geometry expression

Comment: Is `unid = 1` the entire center line skeleton, or is it a segment of that line? `aggregate('line', 'collect', @geometry)` is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't have uniq_id, I've just got example from this site. I have a layer with segments of line and I want to union them all into a Multiline through geometry expression

Comment: See my updated expression. It's what used to make the screenshot.

Comment: thank you! It is what I need

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project.